# How to crimp pages in PostScript?

Tags: printing, postscript

For a toshiba PostScript 3 printer with a unit for crimp/tack/stitch (whatever the correct translation is) I would like to know if there is a way to trigger the crimp by a PostScript command?
As it looks this can be configured in the printer to be done after a complete document has been printed. But I need to print 3 single page documents and then crimp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that whatever PostScript might be used to control this functionality, it is almost certainly device-dependent. Normally this will be done via a call to the setpagdevice operator, but the key name and appropriate values required will be specific to the device.

This might be defined in the documentation for the printer, or on the manufacturer's website. Have you contacted their support desk and asked ?

If for some reason you can't do that, then if you can select this behaviour from (for example) the Windows printer control dialog then it would be possible to 'print' to FILE: and then look at the PostScript to see what has been added to the file to control the behviour.

Finally, if the printer ships with a PPD file then you could look at that, and see what is in there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as I now have researched two PJL sequences:

```
@PUL COMMENT DSSC PRINT HOLEPUNCH=?
```

Where ? could be 0: off, 1: Longe edge, 2: short edge, 3: long edge 10 degree, 4 : short edge 180 degres.

```
@PUL COMMENT DSSC PRINT STAPLING=?
```

Where High byte : lonedge position, low byte : shortedge stapling position